# window.onbeforeunload with a form

Tags: javascript, html

I will try to explain this correctly:

I have a website with a huge form on it. This form has a ton of fields and it all run by another JS file.

To be exact: in my form I have text box's and drop down menus. I want to be able to "reset/refresh" my page after someone leaves it. There's a button at the bottom of the foam that takes you away from the site into a shopping cart.

After going to the shopping cart I want to be able to click the back button and have all the fields reset back to the original state. I tried putting this near the top but it's having no effect. Maybe i'm sticking it in the wrong place?:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    }
   </script>
```

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly is the purpose of this?

Comment: If you reset the form in the `onbeforeunload` event, then the form will be cleared out even before it is submitted, so the form will come to the server appearing to be blank. I don't think that's what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try resetting the form in the `onload` event, which will happen on first load of the form, and also when the user navigates back to the form with the back button:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var frm = document.form1;   // put form name here
    for (var i = 0; i < frm.elements.length; i++)
        frm.elements[i].value = "";
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bavRd/